# Vagrant up command error "There was an error while executing `VBoxManage"

Tags: windows, vagrant

I'm taking udacity's Linux command line basics I was following everything the course said. I installed Virtual box, then vagrant then created a folder in the desktop then downloaded vagrant file to that folder. Then I was supposed to run in my terminal vagrant up, after a few minutes of waiting I get this message, all the course said to do after running vagrant up is to run vagrant ssh but it says I need to run vagrant up first before I can run vagrant ssh. I don't understand what's wrong...

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' version '20190514.0.0' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "7ca8f3db-c969-45a1-93db-06d990751a02", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: The native API dll was not found (C:\windows\system32\WinHvPlatform.dll) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```